# Owner's rent or Rent?

Tags: inflation, statistics

Would you please explain the difference between these?As I know somewhat what their meaning, I can't understand what the second concept.

In addition, I wonder the second one is more important considering the following site  https://www.bls.gov/cpi/factsheets/owners-equivalent-rent-and-rent.htm.

Please excuse me if my first post is messy. Any help would be appreciated.

Rent of primary residence

Owners' equivalent rent of residences

Comment: You might want to clarify where exactly the linked site is giving you a hard time. According to that site, "owner's rent" is an owner's estimate classified as investment whereas "rent" is a verifiable amount that tenants pay and is classified as consumption.